# How to add a row in a JTable when click focus is out of the Table and <ENTER> key is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am designing one client interaction application in which the requirement is as follows:-

1. User had already done editing in the cells.
2. On pressing Enter key new row is inserted.

From the above, if client edit something in a cell and press ENTER key it will make a new row with edit. In other words, when user is out of focus from the cells ENTER key must be used to add a row. And when user has focused one cell and press ENTER it must not add a row.

1. On cell focus + ENTER key pressed = do nothing but edit of cell.
2. Outside cell focus + ENTER key pressed = New row is added.

### SimpleTableDemo

```
package com.ajay.test;

/*
 * SimpleTableDemo.java requires no other files.
 */

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;
    private JTable table = null;

    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                "Last Name",
                                "Sport",
                                "# of Years",
                                "Vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith",
         "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe",
         "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)}};
       

        table = new JTable(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        if (DEBUG) {
            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    printDebugData(table);
                }
            });
        }

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
        .addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
             if(e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)
             {
                  if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                  {
                    addRow();
                  }
             }
             
              return false;
            }
      });
        
        

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }
    
    private void addRow()
    {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();

       if (model != null) {
       Vector v = new Vector(1);
       for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++){
                v.add("");
            }
            model.addRow(v);
            }
               
    }

    private void printDebugData(JTable table) {
        int numRows = table.getRowCount();
        int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
        javax.swing.table.TableModel model = table.getModel();

        System.out.println("Value of data: ");
        for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + model.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please suggest something to add a row if cell focus is not there. And to edit if cell focus is there.

Comment: What about just adding focused KeyBinding ENTER for the JTable? If the editing is in progress there is no focus on the table.

Comment: @StanislavL careful with assumptions on focused: the table can be the focusOwner while editing if its surrenderFocus property is false (forgot if it is by default)

Comment: _click focus_ - what's that? Please stick to swing/awt terminology, otherwise it's extremely difficult to understand what you are asking. Me at least, don't understand your requirement at all ... And note, that KeyListeners are very rarely the solution to _any_ problem, your's doesn't appear to be an exception to that rule - even if it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution for the above problem by the following code:-

```
package com.ajay.test;

/*
 * SimpleTableDemo.java requires no other files.
 */

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;
    private JTable table = null;

    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                "Last Name",
                                "Sport",
                                "# of Years",
                                "Vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith",
         "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe",
         "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)}};


        table = new JTable(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        if (DEBUG) {
            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    printDebugData(table);
                }
            });
        }

        table.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)
                {
                  if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                  {
                    addRow();
                  }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }


        );

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);





        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private void addRow()
    {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();

       if (model != null) {
       Vector v = new Vector(1);
       for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++){
                v.add("");
            }
            model.addRow(v);
            }

    }

    private void printDebugData(JTable table) {
        int numRows = table.getRowCount();
        int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
        javax.swing.table.TableModel model = table.getModel();

        System.out.println("Value of data: ");
        for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + model.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

We also have to add KeyBoardListener in the above code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have get exactly what you want, but only adding a condition in your listener you can do it (If I've understood you):

```
/*
 * SimpleTableDemo.java requires no other files.
 */

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;
    private JTable table = null;

    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                "Last Name",
                                "Sport",
                                "# of Years",
                                "Vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith",
         "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe",
         "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)}};


        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);


        if (DEBUG) {
            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    printDebugData(table);
                }
            });
        }

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
        .addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
             if(e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)
             {
                  if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && table.isEditing()==false)
                  {//HERE IS THE CHANGE
                    addRow();
                  }

             }

              return false;
            }
      });



        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private void addRow()
    {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();

       if (model != null) {
       Vector v = new Vector(1);
       for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++){
                v.add("");
            }
            model.addRow(v);
            }

    }

    private void printDebugData(JTable table) {
        int numRows = table.getRowCount();
        int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
        javax.swing.table.TableModel model = table.getModel();

        System.out.println("Value of data: ");
        for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + model.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With adding the `table.isEditing()==false` condition, you will add a new row when you press `ENTER`, but not if you have just edited a cell and press `ENTER`.